# Web Service Address MonoDevelop

Tags: web-services, web, service, monodevelop

I created a WebService in MonoDevelop, the WebService is running at
 `localhost:8080/LoginUsr.asmx`.

When I try to access from other device, I can't access because the port 8080 is closed for external connections. What can I do?

Comment: Why are you using localhost?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need open this port/connection through firewall. I activated many times with firewall.

Comment: I try to open the port but i cant, i am using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @user7368587 it would be great if you could expand with specific instructions that the OP could use